# Executing a shell script having docker | docker commands not found

Tags: linux, azure, ubuntu, azure-devops, ubuntu-18.04

I created a pipeline in Azure with Ubuntu 18.04. My requirement was to run a docker image using bash script and for the same below script was created but on execution I received an error "docker command does not exist and docker: invalid reference format.

> test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
#
echo "=== docker Images==="
docker images
echo "==== Starut running a jmeter/image ===="
docker run "justb4/jmeter:latest"
echo "==== Finish ===="
```

> Error

```
Starting: Bash Script scripts/test.sh
==============================================================================
Task         : Bash
Description  : Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
Version      : 3.163.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/bash
==============================================================================
Generating script.
Formatted command: bash '/home/vsts/work/1/s/scripts/test.sh' 'justb4/jmeter:latest' mainTest.jmx qa-url 30 1 60 15 2 60 1000
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/5c641c31-4e55-4ab8-be9e-4cf850432bab.sh
=== docker Images===
docker: 'images
' is not a docker command.
See 'docker --help'
==== Starut running a jmeter/image ====
docker: invalid reference format.
See 'docker run --help'.
==== Finish ====

Finishing: Bash Script scripts/test.sh
```

**To describe in detail, here are the tasks created on az pipeline :-**

```
1. Install a docker
```

[image]

```
Output of Task1
```

[image]

```
2. Just for debugging purpose, I added below bash task **with inline commands** to see if docker
```

commands work and it worked perfectly fine with no issues. But in task3, when I tried to execute the 
scripts with the same commands it failed.

[image]

Output of Task2

[image]

```
3. Task 3 to execute test.sh script having docker commands
```

[image]

Output of Task3
[image]

Comment: I copy pasted and all is fine. Are you sure that you don't have any extra character in your test.sh file between `docker` and `images`?

Comment: Thanks for looking into this and giving it a try. There is no space as such and additional characters. Would you please mind confirming how did you execute this script. Is it on Ubuntu image or through Azure pipeline, the same way as I mentioned in the steps.

Comment: I ran the script from Azure Pipelines with `agent Specification` set to `ubuntu-18.04`
`
steps:
- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash Script test.sh'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./stackoverflow/36/test.sh
`

Comment: you did not install a docker, is it not required? I have exactly the same Task which you mentioned above. Still the complete YAML file is here:- Can you figure out any mistake. pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Docker 17.09.0-ce'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'Bash Script scripts/test.sh'
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./scripts/test.sh

Comment: Images in this pool have some software pre-installed. And for instance if you don't install docker a you did it will uses version installed which is int his case `Docker version 3.0.11+azure, build eb310fca49568dccd87c6136f774ef6fff2a1b51`. But I did more. I ran test.sh before installing `Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4` and after. In both cases it works for me.

Comment: Tiring, not able to identify the problem yet. Still looking into this to identify what's wrong. Thanks for all your help. It has almost taken my full day.

Comment: So, all is fine now, or I misunderstood you?

Comment: No, things are not working at my end though the script which you ran at your end and mine are same. Other thing which I noticed that if the same test.sh script, I execute as a inline Type, it worked absolutely fine. 
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
steps:
- task: DockerInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install Docker 17.09.0-ce'

- bash: |
   #!/bin/bash
   #
   echo "=== docker Images==="
   docker images
   echo "==== Starut running a jmeter/image ===="
   docker run "justb4/jmeter:latest"
   echo "==== Finish ===="
  displayName: 'Bash Script scripts/test.sh'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214572/discussion-between-tarun-narang-and-krzysztof-madej).

Comment: Thanks for all your help  Krzysztof Madej. Appreciated. The issue was with what I mentioned in the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Windows or DOS-style line endings but while executing in Azure pipeline it did not throw the actual error. Later it was understood that each line was being terminated with a Carriage Return followed by a Line Feed character. If a script file was saved with Windows line endings, Bash sees the file as

#!/bin/bash^M
 ^M
 cd "src"^M

having a special character at the end.

Try running dos2unix on the script solved the problem.

http://dos2unix.sourceforge.net/

Or just rewrite the script in your Unix env using vi and test.

Unix uses different line endings so can't read the file you created on Windows. Hence it is seeing ^M as an illegal character.

Comment: So, additional characters :) I'm glad you find it ou.